# Removing a child node removes all other nodes

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database looks like this:

```
User Categories
-> User ID
--> Fruits: true
--> Meats: true
--> Drinks
---> Product ID (under drinks node)
----> Product Name
----> Product Price
```

The issue here is if I delete the product ID, the Drinks node gets deleted which is not what I want. I would like to simply delete the product ID node. How can this be done?

This is my current code:

```
DatabaseReference removeProductRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User Categories").child(currentUserID).child(categoryName).child(productId);

removeProductRef.removeValue();
```

Here it will remove the productId child and all the childs within it as well as the Drinks node.

I have also tried to do it like this but the same thing occurs:

```
DatabaseReference removeProductRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User Categories").child(currentUserID).child(categoryName);

removeProductRef.child(productId).removeValue();
```

Workaround:

```
       DatabaseReference removeProductRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User Categories").child(currentUserID).child(categoryName);

        removeProductRef.child(productId).removeValue();

        removeProductRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    // Category exists in database
                } else {
                    removeProductRef.setValue(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                // Handle error
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to have a key without a value in the Firebase Realtime Database.

The Firebase Realtime Database automatically creates a key when you write a value under it for the first time, and it automatically removes a key when you remove the last/only value from under it.

As a workaround while I'm figuring out my data model, I sometimes put a `README` property with a description of the node in place of the actual values. Since my code never deletes this README property, the parent that I have it under will also never be auto-deleted.

Also see:

- [Firebase Realtime Database, setting data keys (without including a value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70726140/firebase-realtime-database-setting-data-keys-without-including-a-value)
- [Create an empty child record in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911165/create-an-empty-child-record-in-firebase)

Comment: Thank you, I added a workaround based on your answer which now works. See OP